# Why was the budget for the Center of Disease Control being cut drastically?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, policy, budget, cdc

Right now, the CDC - according to The Trust for America's Health (TFAH)-  says that the [Center of Disease Control is underfunded by $4.5 billion](https://www.commondreams.org/news/2020/01/21/amid-years-funding-cuts-public-health-first-us-case-chinas-coronavirus-detected) and an act passed on December 22, 2017 cut [$750 million from  the Prevention and Public Health Fund (PPHF), which provides funding to the CDC](https://www.the-scientist.com/daily-news/cuts-to-prevention-and-public-health-fund-puts-cdc-programs-at-risk-30298).  What is the reasoning that the current administration have for performing these cuts to this public health institute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are [some details](http://thenationshealth.aphapublications.org/content/49/3/1.2) on what got cut this year from the CDC (note: there were cuts in the previous Trump years as well)

> Among its proposals for CDC, the White House budget calls for a more than $236 million cut to chronic disease prevention and health promotion, a $146 million cut for the National Institute for Occupational Safety and Health, a more than $102 million cut to emerging and zoonotic diseases, and about a $52 million cut to CDC’s environmental health activities, including funding for asthma and childhood lead poisoning.

So somewhat [standard for the GOP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5922215/) to cut environment and worker-related funding. Also

> The budget proposes a near $20 million cut to injury prevention and control, a more than $30 million cut to public health preparedness and response, and a more than $78 million cut to immunization activities, including work to sustain and improve immunization coverage. The budget also zeros out critical funding for epidemiology and laboratory capacity at state and local levels.

As was noted [elsewhere](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jan/31/us-coronavirus-budget-cuts-trump-underprepared), Trump's administration previously cut the global epidemic budget of the CDC as the administration focused on "American first".

> Funding has also been cut drastically to the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC), forcing it to reduce or discontinue epidemic-prevention efforts in 39 out of the 49 countries it had been helping. Among the countries where CDC efforts were scaled back were Haiti, Rwanda and the Democratic Republic of Congo as well as China, where the agency provided technical assistance.

Perhaps [new to the GOP](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/05/27/anti-vaccine-republican-mainstream-1344955) are vaccine cuts. As somewhat typical of Trump (on [other science issues](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-51213003)) he has [flip-flopped on his vaccine skepticism](https://www.statnews.com/2019/04/26/trump-vaccinations-measles/) too.

By the way, those $750 million were proposed cuts in the White House's version of the budget. [I have a feeling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49948/is-there-a-detailed-comparison-of-what-the-white-house-requested-and-what-cong) most might not have survived encounter with Congress (especially since one chamber is controlled by Democrats), but I can't find the data on what happened with those proposals regarding the CDC.

Comment: This explains the what but not the why. My impression was that the question rather aims at the motivations behind the cuts.

Comment: @Trilarion: do you want some tepid official explanation that the programs cut were "inefficient"?

Comment: This is a political rant, not an answer.

Comment: @JohnK: I'm sure a good, in-depth explanation is found in Trump's twitter feed somewhere, I just went for the low-hanging fruit of [APHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Public_Health_Association)'s breakdown, plus a minimum of historical background. Feel free to write your own insightful answer.