# Is there a (detailed) comparison of what the White House requested and what Congress approved for the HHS for FY2020?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, budget, hhs

To give you an idea what I'm looking for, I found such a [comparison for science](https://www.aaas.org/news/update-age-trump-congress-keeps-boosting-science-funding):

[image]

I'm looking for a similar graph/comparison for the HHS, which includes the NIH, FDA, CDC, SAMHSA, Medicare & Medicaid (CMS) etc. (NIH is actually included in the graph above, but non-research parts of the HHS like the CMS, CDC, FDA, or SAMHSA are not.)

Comment: Somewhat related, Trumps recent passing comments that NIH funds too much stuff: https://www.latimes.com/business/story/2020-04-20/nih-trump-coronavirus-science

Comment: Chart for Selected NIH Institutes at  https://www.aip.org/fyi/2020/final-fy20-appropriations-national-institutes-health